# Overloaded functions with const and non-const return references

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

struct X
{
    int a;
};

struct Y
{
    X x;

    X& GetX()
    {
        printf("non-const version\n");
        return x;
    }

    X const& GetX() const
    {
        printf("const version\n", __FUNCTION__);
        return x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Y y;

    X& i = y.GetX();
    X const& j = y.GetX();

    return 0;
}
```

When run in Code::Blocks 16.01, I get:

```
non-const version
non-const version
```

I often see code like this in the place where I work where you have overloaded functions with different return types. One is a reference, and another is a constant reference.

My questions are: What is the use or benefit of this type of coding, if everything that the const version can do, the non-const version can also do? How do I call the the const version of GetX()? In the case above, the non-const version is always called.

Comment: Function overloading doesn't consider return types.

Comment: try making `y` const

Comment: What if you only have a const value?

Comment: **const** at the return type is ignored except for `cosnt char*`. Turn on your warning complier and you see it tell you as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y is non-const variable. So the non-const method is called.

If you defined y2 as const, it will called the const method.

```
int main()
{
    Y y;
    const Y y2 = y;

    X i = y.GetX();
    const X& j = y2.GetX();

    return 0;
}
```